# separate two stings with double quotes

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

In my script the string value is coming like below

```
QUEUE_VALUE=ABC:CDE
```

I need output is `"ABC","CDE"`

I tried with below command, I am getting output as `ABC","CDE`

```
echo ${QUEUE_NAME} | sed s/:/\"\,\"\/g
```

Could you please help me, Is there any better command to use.

Comment: why do you echo $QUEUE_NAME when your value is in $QUEUE_VALUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`:

```
$ echo $QUEUE_VALUE | sed -e 's/[^:]*/"&"/g' -e 's/:/,/g'
"ABC","CDE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo QUEUE_VALUE=ABC:CDE | awk -F= '{split($2,a,":");print "\"" a[1] "\",\""a[2] "\""}'
"ABC","CDE"
```

`awk` solution: Here split the second field separated by `=` into two parts and format it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

`echo ${QUEUE_NAME} | sed s/:/\"\,\"\/g | sed "s/.*/\"&\"/"`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I believe, given context of the question, this answer is self-explanatory. Especially when two answers above, including accepted one are practically the same

Answer (score 0):

Your sed command does most of what you need.  Replacing each `:` with `","` deals with all the separators.  You'll then want to replace both the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the input with a double-quote:

```sh
echo "$QUEUE_VALUE" | sed -e 's/:/","/g' -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/'
```

In the above, I've written the sed commands in single quotes, because we don't want any expansion, and we can write more clearly without needing lots of backslashes.

---

This is a substitution we can do with Bash.  The main part is written `"${QUEUE_VALUE//:/\",\"}"` (or `"${QUEUE_VALUE//:/'","'}"` for simpler quoting), and adding the initial and final quotes is easy:

```
echo \""${QUEUE_VALUE//:/'","'}"\"
```

---

An alternative way of thinking is to replace any run of characters that isn't `:` with the same run wrapped in a pair of quotes, then replace every `:` with a comma.  The sed command for that is

```
sed -e 's/[^:]*/"&"/g' -e 'y/:/,/'
```

(Note that we match *zero or more* non-colon characters, so that empty elements get quoted correctly.)  This is something which can't so easily be done in pure Bash.